# How to compile all open files (or selected files from Notepad++ Explorer) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have set up compiling (mostly SQL Server) in Notepad++, and it works fine.  But I would like to be able to compile many files at once.  I might edit 3-10 files at one time, then like to hit a button and compile them all at once.

I tried a macro recording Control-Tab (switch windows) then Control-F6 (execute previous), but the macro seems to hang when switching windows.

I've been through the console help options in NppExec and thought that $(#n) [the name of the file in the nth open window] had promise, but there are two basic problems: no if command and no branching/looping commands in NppExec console.

I've also tried using Npp Explorer's ability to select various files and run a NppExec script on them.  Within the specially crafted exec script the line

```
//Explorer: NppExec.dll EXP_FULL_PATH[0]
```

passes the *first* file selected, while

```
//Explorer: NppExec.dll EXP_FULL_PATH[0] EXP_FULL_PATH[1]
```

would I imagine pass both the first and the second.  But I don't see how to pass all files that are selected in Npp Explorer.  If I could get that, I could have NppExec script call a DOS command or powershell script to compile all files that were passed.

I appreciate any suggestions.